# Hebrew encoding in sql server2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, encoding, hebrew

i try this code in sql server 2005

```
declare @userName nvarchar(50)
set @userName='איש2'    
print @userName
```

but i get this

```
???2
```

what is the cause?

it look like it replace the Hebrew char to "?"

10x

Comment: FWIW I get the same in SQL 2008 management studio and the same in the table view if I insert the string into a table. So it's getting lost somewhere, and it's not obvious to me if that's the read in or the print back.

Comment: Some more data points: if I enter that string into a field in my app, it saves correctly. If I view the table in management studio then the table view shows me the Hebrew characters but they're backwards. If I select the value into an nvarchar in the console and print it, it prints in the message window correctly. So I'd guess the problem is the console reading the string?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query.
I've tried it in my Microsoft SQL management studio (2008)
and it works... 

this must be something in your settings... but I don't know what.

Comment: @Asaf - I presume that you were running it under the context of a database whose default collation is hebrew - which is why it worked for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `N` prefix so the string literal is interpreted as unicode not char under the code page of whatever your database's default collation is

```
declare @userName nvarchar(50)
set @userName=N'איש2'    
print @userName
```