# How to pass SQL stored procedure NVARCHAR parameter with Hebrew?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, unicode, hebrew

I'm trying to pass an `NVARCHAR` parameter to my store procedure. The stored procedure is supposed to find all suppliers that match the specified criteria. The only problem I have is that I am trying to pass criteria that contains Hebrew.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindSupplier] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @search_criteria nvarchar(100) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @hebrew as bit = 0

    IF @search_criteria LIKE '%[אבגדהוזחטיחכךילמנפףערקשת]%'
    BEGIN
        SET @hebrew = 1
    END

    IF @hebrew = 0 
    BEGIN

        SELECT comn020.t_suno 'Supplier Code'
        , hebcom020.t_nama 'Supplier Name1'
            , hebcom020.t_namb 'Supplier Name2'

        FROM com020 WITH (NOLOCK)

        INNER JOIN hebcom020 WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON hebcom020.t_suno = com020.t_suno

        WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM(com020.t_suno)) LIKE N'%' + @search_criteria + '%')
           OR (SOUNDEX(LTRIM(RTRIM(com020.t_suno))) LIKE N'%' + SOUNDEX(@search_criteria) + '%')
           OR (LTRIM(RTRIM(hebcom020.t_nama)) LIKE N'%' + @search_criteria + '%')
           OR (SOUNDEX(LTRIM(RTRIM(hebcom020.t_nama))) LIKE N'%' + SOUNDEX(@search_criteria) + '%')
           OR (LTRIM(RTRIM(hebcom020.t_namb)) LIKE N'%' + @search_criteria + '%')
           OR (SOUNDEX(LTRIM(RTRIM(hebcom020.t_namb))) LIKE N'%' + SOUNDEX(@search_criteria) + '%')

    END

    ELSE  /* hebrew */
    BEGIN
        SELECT com020.t_suno 'Supplier Code'
             , hebcom020.t_nama 'Supplier Name1'
             , hebcom020.t_namb 'Supplier Name2'

        FROM com020 WITH (NOLOCK)

        INNER hebcom020 WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON hebcom020.t_suno = com020.t_suno

        WHERE hebcom020.t_nama Collate Hebrew_CI_AI LIKE N'%' + @search_criteria + '%' Collate Hebrew_CI_AI
            OR (LTRIM(RTRIM(hebcom020.t_namb)) LIKE N'%' + @search_criteria + '%')
    END

END
```

When I'm trying to pass something like `exec FindSupplier 'ב'` the SQL server recognizes char 'ב' as '?'

Your help will be highly appreciated

UPD: `exec FindSupplier N'ב'` worked

UPD2: In Visual Studio need to run sp with following string

```
="exec FindSupplier N'" & Parameters!search_criteria.Value & "'"
```

Comment: Here's a related question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438483/hebrew-encoding-in-sql-server2005

Comment: Jason, it is not the same case... I need to handle sp parameter, not declared variable

Comment: This doesn't work? exec FindSupplier N'ב'

Comment: @IgorM If you post a problem and then figure it out before anyone answers, then you should post the answer to help others that might be having the same problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply that the string literal used in the `LIKE` condition is *not* prefixed with an `N` to indicate that it is a Unicode string. The following example shows the difference:

```sql
DECLARE  @search_criteria NVARCHAR(100) = N'ב';

IF @search_criteria LIKE '%[אבגדהוזחטיחכךילמנפףערקשת]%'
BEGIN
    PRINT 'WithOUT "N"-prefix';
END;

IF @search_criteria LIKE N'%[אבגדהוזחטיחכךילמנפףערקשת]%'
BEGIN
    PRINT 'WITH "N"-prefix';
END;
```

Returns:

```
WITH "N"-prefix
```

To more easily understand *why* there is this difference in behavior, consider the following:

```
-- when the DB has a default collation of Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC (code page 1252)
SELECT  '%[אבגדהוזחטיחכךילמנפףערקשת]%'
-- %[????????????????????????]%

-- when the DB has a default collation of Hebrew_100_CI_AS_SC (code page 1255)
SELECT  '%[אבגדהוזחטיחכךילמנפףערקשת]%'
-- %[אבגדהוזחטיחכךילמנפףערקשת]%
```

The string literals are parsed in the code page used by the default collation of the *current* database. If the code page can support these characters, then not prefixing with the upper-case "N" will work. But, if those characters do not exist in that code page, then they are converted into "?"s.